# Convert an in-process COM server to out-of-process

Tags: windows, delphi, c++builder, com+, outlook-redemption

I am currently using an in-process COM server (Outlook Redemption) in my application and I need to convert it to work out-of-process, I'm using C++ Builder.

From what I've read so far, I believe I need to create the new COM server as a .exe, but how do I do that? and how do I make all the the existing functions visible? Can that be done automatically via the existing TLB or do I have to create wrappers around all the functions that I will need?

Any guidance to put me on the right track would be really welcome.

Edit: If anyone is able to explain the process for Delphi instead, I'm sure I'd be able to adapt it.

Comment: I woudln't do that if I were you - making sure your code always uses absolute file paths (since the current directory can be reset by the MAPI system) is a much better alternative.

Comment: Why do you need to convert the COM server from in-proc to out-of-proc? Unless you wrote the COM server yourself, you can't just convert it. But you can write your own COM out-of-proc server that uses the in-proc server internally. Or, you can try wrapping the in-proc server in a [DLL Surrogate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/dll-surrogates), which handles the out-of-proc portion for you.